Parameter with spaces in datafactory business central
In datafactory i try to make a rest api get request to only get results of the past few days so i want to filter on postingdate but datafactory is replacing the spaces of the parameter woth %20 and now the get request is not working.

printscreen of error

printscreen of parameter
What the api url is supposed to end up looking like
https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/abc/abc/api/abc/extendedPowerBI/v2.0/companies(abc)/valueEntries?$select=entryNo,externalDocumentNo,varianceType,dimensionSetID,documentNo,orderLineNo,documentLineNo,no,postingDate,costPerUnit,type,invoicedQuantity,documentDate,locationCode,genProdPostingGroup,inventoryPostingGroup,salespersPurchCode,itemLedgerEntryType,itemLedgerEntryQuantity,itemLedgerEntryNo,itemNo,sourceNo,sourceCode,costAmountExpected,costAmountActual,salesAmountActual,documentType,itemChargeNo,costAmountNonInvtbl,entryType,discountAmount&$filter=postingDate gt 2024-11-10


Is it the dataset parameter? or pipeline parameter? and provide the expected sample URL?

i edited to show what the the expected sample url is supposed to look like. But i would like to make the filter that the posting date is equal to the last date that is currently in the sql table. So i can append only new records. @RakeshGovindula

Is it a dataset parameter right?

yes @RakeshGovindula

If the above values resulting the characters %20 in the place of spaces, you can try to achieve your expression by reversing the expression.
&$filter=postingDate%20gt%202024-11-10

Try the above value in the parameter.

If it does not work, you can try the below dynamic expression in the dataset parameter.
@concat('&$filter=postingDate',decodeUriComponent('%20'),'gt',decodeUriComponent('%20'),'2024-11-10')

This expression converts the above characters into spaces and concatenates with the URL properties.

